# Create dynamic menu: call js file different depending on the size of the window? (mobile or desktop)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drop-down-menu

Hello guys I need your own opinion ...

I had the crazy idea to create from scratch a menu for my site, a menu that changes when used from the desktop or the mobile. I worked on the menu by separating the two tasks (creating the menu for the desktop and elsewhere that for mobile). The two files js worked great ... the problem occurred when I put together the two files.

Each file js intervenes on html code going to hang (append) portions of code html or going to change some css properties. So when I switch from one mode to another (via the resize () of the window and depending on its width) I find the changes from the other file.

To fix everything, I'm afraid I'll have to add several lines of code .... or is there another solution?

I had thought of adding the Head one of the two files, depending on the width of the window. If we are over 980px then I add the js file to create the menu for the desktop, or add one to the mobile.

I tried in this way:

```
 $("head").append('<script type="text/javascript" src="' + script + '"></script>');
```

but it did not work...

thanks and sorry for my english

Comment: Indeed this is a crazy idea. Especially when there exist things like `Responsive Design`. :)  `menu that changes when used from the desktop or the mobile`

Comment: Learn more about `CSS media queries`. Learn about `bootstrap`. You don't need to do this with JavaScript. We are in 2015. :) (unless you are doing this to improve your own understanding of the language. )

Comment: I did it to learn more about this language (especially jquery) but also because I will not weigh down even more, using other libraries